# How to find the text inside a Base64 encoded image?

Tags: image, base64, decode

Recently, I got familiar with the images in Base64 format which are mostly used in Captcha like this:

```html
<div style="background:white url('data:image/jpg;base64,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') no-repeat scroll left top;width:350px;height:50px;margin:2em;display:block;">&nbsp;</div>
```

I would like to know is there any solution to read the text inside this image by decoding the Base64 codes or something else?

Answer (score 0):

No; such a solution would enable a robot to pass the test.